# Deprecated alias does not generate a warning

Tags: rust

I have a library that used to have a top-level public trait (call it `FlatMap`) implemented for `Option`. Now I have refactored my library and moved that trait into a submodule named `option`, and I have ensured backward compatibility by publicly importing `FlatMap` into the top-level of the crate. I would like to warn users of the top-level trait that it is deprecated. I have tried the following:

```
pub mod option {
   pub trait FlatMap<T> {}
}
#[deprecated(note="Use option::FlatMap instead")]
pub use option::FlatMap;
```

However this does not work: I can now `use mylib::FlatMap` and `use mylib::option::FlatMap` and either works fine with no warning. I would like the first use to generate a deprecation warning.

Note that I can't use an alias trait like this:

```
pub mod option {
   pub trait FlatMap<T> {}
}
#[deprecated(note="Use option::FlatMap instead")]
pub trait FlatMap<T>: option::FlatMap<T> {}
impl<T> FlatMap<T> for Option<T> {}
```

because I rely on implicit conversion from `Option` to `option::FlatMap` to add a method to `Option` instances, and the implicit conversion does not work with the aliased trait.

Comment: Why don't you use `impl<T: option::FlatMap> FlatMap for T {}` for the alias trait?

Comment: @Stefan because I didn't think of it. However it doesn't work either: the implicit conversions still don't work with the aliased trait.

Comment: Under what circumstances must`Option` convert implicitly to `option::FlatMap`? Could you perhaps `impl Deref for FlatMap { type Target=option::FlatMap; ... }` to make it work again?

Comment: @trentcl The `FlatMap` trait adds a `flat_map` method to option objects which I then call as `o.flat_map(...)`. I need this because it's actually called by a macro that must work transparently with iterators and `Option` (and `Result` and any user-defined type that defines the `map` and `flat_map` methods). The full code of my crate is on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/jmb/rust-map_for/src/5ba07063d242381fa120bf4bba33d679e02376aa/src/lib.rs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#lib.rs-97).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being able to call `option::FlatMap` methods on an `Option` isn't a conversion, implicit or otherwise -- it's just how methods are resolved. Trait methods may be resolved on an object if the trait has been `use`d, but the top level `FlatMap` trait has no methods, so it doesn't add anything to the object at all.

It seems the best way to achieve this in Rust right now is to copy the trait (*with* all its contents) into the top level, annotate it `#[deprecated]`, and write a blanket `impl` that defers to the "real" version.

```
pub mod option {
    pub trait FlatMap<T> {
        type Item;
        type FlatMap;
        fn flat_map<F>(self, f: F) -> Self::FlatMap
        where
            F: FnOnce(Self::Item) -> T;
    }
    // ...
}

#[deprecated(note = "Use option::FlatMap instead")]
pub trait FlatMap<T> {
    type Item;
    type FlatMap;
    fn flat_map<F>(self, f: F) -> Self::FlatMap
    where
        F: FnOnce(Self::Item) -> T;
}

#[allow(deprecated)]
impl<T, U> FlatMap<T> for U
where
    U: option::FlatMap<T>,
{
    type Item = U::Item;
    type FlatMap = U::FlatMap;
    fn flat_map<F>(self, f: F) -> Self::FlatMap
    where
        F: FnOnce(Self::Item) -> T,
    {
        option::FlatMap::flat_map(self, f)
    }
}
```

Any attempt to use the "outer" `FlatMap` will generate the deprecation warning ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8afb5d028e87e3531998e3297f07b98d&version=stable)).

One limitation of this approach (besides the verbosity) is that the two traits won't be compatible as trait objects (e.g., you couldn't pass an `&FlatMap` to a function expecting `&option::FlatMap`.) However, this trait isn't object safe anyway, so in this case it doesn't matter.

*As it happens, your definition of `flat_map` -- while a generalization of `and_then` -- is a different generalization than [several](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Optional/#func-flatmap_) [other](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) [languages](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Option.html#flatMap%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EOption%5BB%5D):Option%5BB%5D) use, including [Rust's own `Iterator::flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map). So you might want to consider renaming it. (I think `map_or_default` would fit in well, name-wise, with the other methods available on [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html).)*

Comment: Like I said, I need it to be called `flat_map` for duck-typing purposes. Actually it started as a straight equivalent for `and_then`, the current generalization evolved from an attempt to make it possible to mix options and iterators transparently (I needed a generic way to create an empty instance of any iterator, and I was hoping without looking at the docs that iterators implemented `Default` that way).